# Why javax.xml.stream.XMLEventReader.next() cannot be cast to XMLEvent during compile time?

Tags: java, xml-parsing

Can anybody explain me why this code does not compile:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLEventReader;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.events.XMLEvent;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        XMLEventReader xr = XMLInputFactory.newInstance().createXMLEventReader(new FileInputStream("test.xml"));
        XMLEvent e = xr.next();
    }
}
```

output

```
Test.java:10: error: incompatible types
        XMLEvent e = xr.next();
                            ^
  required: XMLEvent
  found:    Object
1 error
```

According to API XMLEventReader.next() returns XMLEvent.

Note: I used javac 1.7.0_03

Comment: You can cast an `Object` to an `XMLEvent` - but you will need to actually do it, write a cast expression. Here, you're not casting, just trying to make an illegal assignment.

Comment: because you need `nextEvent()` method, `next()` is from Iterator, that is parent class for XMLEventReader

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interface `XMLEventReader` extends the raw type `Iterator`, not the parameterized type `Iterator<XMLEvent>`, so `next()` will return `Object`.  You should use `nextEvent()` instead, which does return `XMLEvent`.